# Python 3.3.2 - how to run script on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have nothing to do with Python, just needed it for one script from [Adding a prefix to Bootstrap CSS classes](http://longtermcache.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/adding-prefix-to-bootstrap-css-classes.html).
In "how-to" author instruct to call the script in this way:

```
$python bootstrap_namespace_prefixer.py /path/to/boostrap/dir
```

so in command line I have typed

```
$python bootstrap_namespace_prefixer.py c:\bootstrap
```

which is giving me an error

```
File "", line 1
$python bootstrap_namespace_prefixer.py c:\bootstrap
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the link to script on [github](https://github.com/faucamp/bootstrap_namespace_prefixer/blob/master/bootstrap_namespace_prefixer.py)
As I said I'm not Python programmer, just need this script to help me in my work, but have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Did you try running that command from the Python console? It should be run from the command prompt.

Comment: The $ is part of commonly used Unix prompts. You should leave it off.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the `Python`?

- Install [`Python`](http://www.python.org/download/), choose any version you like: [`x64`](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.amd64.msi) or [`x86`](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.msi).
- Add `Python` to `PATH`:

  - Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
  - Click `Advanced System Settings`.
  - Click `Environment Variables`.
  - Append `;C:\Python33` to the `PATH` variable.
- Restart the `cmd.exe` or `Powershell`.
- Try running `python bootstrap_namespace_prefixer.py c:\bootstrap`.

Comment: Yep,  did that. Actually got the answer - I used the $ prefix before python.